# How to run a shell command in RPM spec file?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

How do I run a shell command in spec file? I want to execute something similar like:

```
uname -r | sed s/(...stuff...)/(...stuff...)
```

Comment: Each part of the spec file is a script that runs shell commands. Where do you want this command to run?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need it in something like a `%define` or `%global` or a macro, you can use "`%(shell_command)`". Note `()` not `{}`.